# Is "chain of responsibity" an appropriate design pattern for validation?

Tags: validation, design-patterns, language-agnostic

I have an application in which i should validate different kinds of things on the same object. So it came in my mind to use chain of resposibility design pattern, problem is that this patters defines that if certain object in chain fails, the client will be notified right away while i want to go thought all the objects (validator) in chain so each one of these will return result (passed/failed + exception).

```
var validator = new Validator(dataObject)
validator.Validate();
```

Is it acceptable use case or is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your validation according to your requirements should not *return early*, this is less like a **chain**, but rather a **list**.  Which simply can be *iterated* over or be *processed parallel*.

*Decorators* can be used to combine validators, too.

Comment: Jens, thanks for fixing the title. I'm bad in giving titles. I get about the lists which was the design i've made year back to more or less the same issue but i can't get what decorators will give me ? Can you explain ?

Comment: Well that in short is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/72421/1725096). The answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4376394/1725096) look interesting, too.